# how to assign the size of 2-D matrix to two new variable in r?

Tags: r, matlab

This is what I know in Matlab and want do same in r programming

```
 A=[1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9];

 A =

   1     2     3
   4     5     6
   7     8     9 

[m,n]=size(A)

m=3
n=3
```

so here I have two distinct variables to which the dimension or size of 2D matrix is assigned automatically

```
 > x<-c(1:10)
 > x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

 > A=matrix(0,10,10)
 > A=Toeplitz(x,c(x[1],rev(x[-1])))
 > A

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2
 [2,]    2    1   10    9    8    7    6    5    4     3
 [3,]    3    2    1   10    9    8    7    6    5     4
 [4,]    4    3    2    1   10    9    8    7    6     5
 [5,]    5    4    3    2    1   10    9    8    7     6
 [6,]    6    5    4    3    2    1   10    9    8     7
 [7,]    7    6    5    4    3    2    1   10    9     8
 [8,]    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1   10     9
 [9,]    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    10
 [10,]   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2     1

 > n=size(A)
 > n
 [1] 10 10

 >[ m,n]=size(A)
```

this is not working so is there any way to assign the size of the 2Dmatrix to two distinct variable m and n in r.I am learning r programming and need help

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly, but what about `c(m, n) %<-% size(A)`? This is part of the `zeallot` package, so you'd need to do `library(zeallot)` first (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeallot/vignettes/unpacking-assignment.html)

Comment: @KenHBS it is working, Thanks a lot.

Comment: or `m <- nrow(A); n <- ncol(A)` ?